# What happened to the old hamburger menu?

Tags: firefox, gui

I remember pre-quantum Firefox having a hamburger menu with icons which you could customize:

[image]

However my current version of Firefox (60.0) seems to have lost it in favor of a more classic menu woth rows.

[image]

Was the old one removed with the coming of Firefox Quantum?
It seems like a step backwards. Is it possible to get it back somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> Was the old one removed with the coming of Firefox Quantum?

That would seem to be the case. The new style menu was present in Firefox 57 ("Quantum"). From the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/57.0/releasenotes/):

> A redesigned interface with a clean, modern appearance, consistent visual elements, and optimizations for touch screens

Although it is admittedly hard to see how the new style menu is an "optimization for touch screens".

> Is it possible to get it back somehow?

I see no way to revert to the old *icon* style menu. "Themes" don't appear to be able to control this. However, there is still a customizable ("overflow") menu (although I don't see this in your screenshot):

[image: Firefox Customizable "Overflow" Menu]

Comment: I'd call it an optimization for humans though... Scanning a menu in one direction is a bit faster than two. And a new or removed menu item only results in a small shift for the rest, not a complete reshuffle.

Comment: @grawity Yes, I agree. Personally, I do prefer the "new" menu _list_.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't so much that the icons are gone as that they have moved.

In the earlier hamburger menu, that collection of often used icons was displayed in the popup window as soon as you clicked the hamburger.  If you went to the bottom of that menu and clicked Customize, it took you to another tab, and more icons were shown there.  So the icons were split into two groups.

In the new hamburger menu, you click Customize (now stuck in the middle of the menu instead of the bottom).  You get the Customize tab with the icons, and all of them are there in one group instead of being split up.